# Using a ListBox with custom range

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to solve the following:

1. Create a ListBox with a range of 100 values for example in this order:

   ...0.1 0.2 1 1.3 1.6 1.9 3 10.3 30 ...
2. When any value is selected in the ListBox `A1` is set to that value.
3. `A2` is set to whatever value is before.

For example from the series above:

```
1.6 is selected in Listbox then A1==1.6 and A2 == 1.3
```

What I'm having problems with is how to define a custom range of number which I can use from many places in VBA, for example to populate the ListBox with and to use arithmetic on. My first thought is to use a Dictionary where the keys are 1..100 and the values are my range. However my limited experience with VBA in Excel makes me unsure how to even begin using such a data structure.

My question is:
What is the best way to solve the following problem using VBA in Excel?

Comment: You can create a `Named Range`. First create the list you want on a different sheet and then see the 'Define a Name for a Cell or Cell Range on  a Worksheet" section here: https://support.office.com/en-gb/article/Define-and-use-names-in-formulas-4d0f13ac-53b7-422e-afd2-abd7ff379c64  You can then add your names range to the `RowSource` property of the list box

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no need to over-complicate by using VBA for such a simple task.

[image]

On the other hand, it sure sounds like *homework*!  If you "have to" simply record a macro doing the same steps, then edit the macro and you will see the VBA code.  Kind of cheating, but hey...

More reading [here](https://analysistabs.com/vba-code/excel-userform/listbox/).